# How to validate that the properties of an object are empty in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to validate if my object in its properties are empty or null.

```
    const references = {
      reference1 : {
          "name" : "",
          "phone" : ""
      },
      reference2 : {
          "name" : null,
          "phone" : null
      }  
   }
```

I have tried to do the following but it is not what I am really looking for

```
console.log(Object.keys(references.reference1).lenght == 0)
```

Comment: Mate you've got length spelling typo.

Comment: I sense one-liners coming up

Comment: `Object.keys` returns all property names of an object, no matter if their property value is empty or not. You'll need to test the actual values.

Comment: You have a duplicate key `reference1`. The first object will be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**See [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) on MDN:**

> The **`Object.values()`** method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values.
>
> The **`every()`** method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

```js
function allPropsNull(object) {
   return Object.values(object).every(value => value === null);
}
function allPropsEmptyString(object) {
   return Object.values(object).every(value => value === "");
}

const obj1 = {
   "name" : null,
   "phone" : null
};
const obj2 = {
   "name" : "",
   "phone" : ""
};
const obj3 = {
   "name" : "",
   "phone" : null
};
console.log('Expected true|false:', allPropsNull(obj1), allPropsEmptyString(obj1));
console.log('Expected false|true:', allPropsNull(obj2), allPropsEmptyString(obj2));
console.log('Expected false|false:', allPropsNull(obj3), allPropsEmptyString(obj3));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the collaboration, I was able to solve it with @Niklas E. comment